# HTML datalist accessibility with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wai-aria, html-datalist

I am filling an HTML datalist with options coming from Angular ng-repeat.

I need this datalist to work with a screen reader, that should be naming the available options while you type in.

This is my code:

```
<input aria-label="Tag" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-owns="categories" ng-model="categoryFilter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category" list="categories">

<datalist id="categories" role="listbox">
  <option role="option" ng-repeat="restaurant in main.restaurants | unique: 'venue.categories[0].name'" value="{{restaurant.venue.categories[0].name}}">
</datalist>
```

I have tried with different `aria-autocomplete` values but nothing seems to work, when I use the screen reader i am getting information that is a combo box, but if I start for example to type 'p' datalist is showing 'Pizzeria' as an option but screen reader is not naming it.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'd start by looking into [ARIA live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions).

Comment: i tried it but is not working, i have tried adding to datalist `<datalist id="categories" role="listbox" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" aria-atomic="true">` (i tried with and without aria-relevant and aria-atomic)

Comment: Has a screen reader user flagged this as an issue/bug? When entering the field, the SR will indicate that it is an auto-complete field. The user would then start typing and can arrow down to hear the options. This is a known interaction to the user. What you do not want to do is overwhelm the user with spoken options.

Comment: I haven't tested with a real user yet, but i thought that will be useful for the user to know the options, i didn't manage to solve it so i move my code to a `<select>` maybe i should have consider it in the first place. Thanks

Comment: I think your approach was initially fine, but you assumed an issue without testing. That's common, but also creates a lot of kvetching for no reason. If you have a chance to test with a user, give your original idea a whirl.